# Rails 7 validation to prevents delete AdminUser if its last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got Rails 7 app with `AdminUser` model. There can be multiple Admins in which anyone can remove any administrator. How do I set the validation so that it blocks the possibility of deleting `AdminUser` if this one is the last one in the db?

In a nutshell I want to have always one undelitable AdminUser.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to stop the user from deleting themselves?

Comment: I think it's better to prevent self deleting. And it's better to do this in authorization layer

Comment: Why exactly? User should be able to delete their account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would add an `AdminUser#destroyable?` to allow checking in the frontend if a destroy is possible and if a link should be rendered in the view.

```
# in app/models/admin_user.rb
def destroyable?
  AdminUser.count > 1
end
```

This can be used in the view like this:

```
<%= link_to(admin_user_path ...) if admin_user.destroyable? %>
```

Then you can raise an exception when someone tries to destroy the last admin user.

```
# in app/models/admin_user.rb
before_destoy :do_not_destroy_last_admin

private

def do_not_destroy_last_admin
  raise(
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed, "Last admin cannot be deleted" 
  ) unless destroyable?
end
```

Comment: May be it's better in frontend check if current user is this admin and in backend permit self-deleting

Comment: Admin authorization is, of course, required in the frontend and backend. I am not sure about permitting self-deletion because then the last admin user could still delete itself and then there are no admin users left.

Comment: Oh, of course *don't* permit I mean

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback like `before_destroy`.

```
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :check_last
  ...
  private 

  def check_last
    return unless AdminUser.size < 2
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed, 'Can\'t delete last Admin'
  end
end
```